# Bash script to take screenshot and save the image - Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I wrote a bash script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a file name"
read filename
import -window root $HOME/Desktop/$filename.png
```

I expected this script to take a screen shot and save the image with the given filename on m desktop....

Problem: My ubuntu terminal is giving error. import: Command Not Found

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that's "import" from imagemagick:

sudo apt-get install imagemagick

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while true; do scrot -d 900 'DEMO%d-%H:%M:%S.png' -e 'mv $f /home/'; done
```